# SQL query won't build correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a query which shows 5 results with the highest views on a set month;
the query on its own with static dates works fine, but when I try using the `date()` function to get the current year and month it doesn't work:

```
$currentmonth = date("m");
$nextmonth = $currentmonth++;
$gethotbookq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT BookID, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM `BOOKS_views` WHERE `TIME` >= '2014- $currentmonth-01 00:00:00' and `TIME` < '2014-$nextmonth-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY `BookID` LIMIT 5") or die();
```

Comment: change `$nextmonth = $currentmonth++;` to `$nextmonth = $currentmonth+1;`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: worked perfectly, Iv'e been trying to figure it out for about 15 minutes.

Comment: It's often worth separating the creation of the SQL string from the query method, so you can echo out the query before it is sent to the database server.

Comment: if you add $nextmonth = $currentmonth++; then suppose the $currentmonth is 12 the $nextmonth will be 13. Problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 $currentmonth = date("m");
 $nextmonth    = date("m", strtotime(" +1 month"));
 $gethotbookq  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT BookID, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM `BOOKS_views` WHERE `TIME` >= '2014-$currentmonth-01 00:00:00' and `TIME` < '2014-$nextmonth-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY `BookID` LIMIT 5") or die();
```